# Transportation representation Standard on roads

Tags: transportation, representation, network

Is there a GIS standard to display transportation specific information in GIS databases. 
The information I'm interested in are:

- Road Directionality
- Center turning lanes
- Ramps / Bridges / Over or under passes / culverts / merge lanes
- grade / crown / ditch
- Traffic Signals and timing
- allowable turning movements, u turns / left / right / through turns, penalties or bonuses(Time)

As we're all aware, transportation data is very general and includes a lot of fields. The only resource that address this are [GIS-T book by Milelr](http://www.amazon.ca/Geographic-Information-Systems-Transportation-Applications/dp/0195123948/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279894407&sr=8-1), [ESRI's designing transportation databases book](http://www.amazon.ca/Designing-Geodatabases-Transportation-Allison-Butler/dp/158948164X/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1279894438&sr=1-1-fkmr0), and a few papers by [Michael Goodchild](http://www.urisa.org/hall/goodchild)

Some Software like TransCAD, Emme 2/3, and ArcGIS have their own ways of representing network topology. It'll be interesting if there was a standard that all software companies can adhere too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the [INSPIRE data specification for transport networks](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_TN_v3.1.pdf) could be usefull?
It uses a generic model of networks presented in [this document](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/D2.5_v3_3.pdf), part 9.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [OSM Binary format](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Binary_Format) might come close. It's not really a "standard" in the formal sense however.

I wonder if an extension to KML could efficiently store road metadata. It seems like it could be easily inserted into the current KML schema.